# XAML formatting error when using <Style>

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed in a few places that XAML code sometimes formats incorrectly like the third code block on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107470/enabling-scrollviewer-horizontalsnappoints-with-bindable-collection).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with the code formatting?

You can also see the issue on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302932/how-to-change-the-border-on-un-selected-items-in-a-listbox) in the question and the second code block on the accepted answer.

**Update:** It appears this is an issue with the content of `<Style>` tags.

Comment: That is a bit odd.

Comment: We don't have any special highlighting for xaml. `lang-xml` from prettify.js is used.

Comment: @m0sa So the bug is in prettify.js?  Is there someone I need to talk to for this bug to get fixed, or should this meta question take care of it.  As I have been using SO I have realized that the issue is with `<Setter>` tags.  I am not sure why the bug exists, but it should be fairly easy to find and fix.

Comment: This was answered on MSE but I can't seem to find it anymore...

Comment: @BoltClock Do you remember if the answer was the same as Stijn's?  I still think this is a bug which could be fixed, so I am not sure if I should accept his answer or if leaving it unaccepted will prompt the moderators to get a XML specific version of prettify.js.

Comment: @Trisped: Yes, although to be honest, that answer was mostly an intelligent guess on my part :P But it makes sense. And I see that it's finally been reported now - it wasn't yet reported at the time the earlier question was asked.

Comment: @m0sa would it help if we *did* have `lang-xaml`? I'm not familiar with the defs in prettify.js, but if `lang-xaml` was a copy of `lang-xml` without the special processing for `<style>` elements, that would seem like a quick fix to an annoying problem.

Comment: @BobSammers I'm sure they accept [pull requests](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pulls)

Comment: @m0sa No doubt. I've been looking at the code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in prettify.js: [Issue 280: Code in <Style>-Tags is not highlighted as XML when using lang-xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=280)

> The reason is that both HTML and XML are parsed using the same lexer:
>
> https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js#1294
>
> which detects <style> and <script> tags inside the markup

Comment: It is not just `<Style>` tags.  It is also `<Setter>` tags.

Comment: @Trisped `<Setter>` is irrelevant, see [this Formatting Sandbox post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231070/167646) Everything inside `<Style>` will be highlighted as if it was CSS.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by irrelevant, `<Setter>` is the reason I started this bug report.  If you go to the first two links you will see examples of the bug.  The `<Style>` tag was an issue I found recently so I added it to the bug report so the report would be as complete as possible.

Comment: @Trisped In the first two examples `<Setter>` is inside a `<Style>` too.

Answer (score 2):

Until commenter Bob Sammers fixes the Google code :), a work-around that I find useful is to declare a namespace name in the XAML, and then use it for the `<Style>` elements.

For example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
  <p:Style TargetType="Button">
    <!-- etc. -->
  </p:Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This provides a fix that works around the bug in the formatter, while avoiding uncompilable code in a code example.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I've used `<Sty1e>` (i.e. a digit `1` instead of the `l`) for the opening tags:

```xml
<Style>
    <Setter />
</Style>
```

becomes

```xml
<Sty1e>
    <Setter />
</Style>
```

There is clearly a potential problem with this if anyone doesn't realise and copy / pastes your code... probably best to flag it up if using!

Seems like a good enough reason to introduce a specific `lang-xaml` lexer to me though, or at least a modification to the XML one to a) accept `lang-xaml` as a selector and b) disable special processing for the `<style>` tags when it's in use. Does SO use a stock version or maintain a fork?